# Ant global <compilerarg> property

Tags: ant, compiler-construction, javac, eclipse-jdt

I need to set two global  properties to be used with invocation of javac in my ant script.

Currently I have this in each of my javac invocations:

```
<compilerarg compiler="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter" line="-1.6 -warn:none"/>
```

I tried to set a global property like this

```
<property name="compiler.args" value="-1.6 -warn:none" />
```

But only the first argument is given to javac, the second is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

As per : http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg , one can have space for `line` attribute of `compilerarg`.

```
line    a space-delimited list of command-line arguments.
```

Just using is below is resulting in any specific error, after `property` is set?

```
<compilerarg compiler="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter" line="${compiler.args}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, the <compilerarg> tag does support line as you've stated but it is only applicable to be nested within the <javac> tag. I don't want to nest this within all of my <javac> tags, I need a global property/attribute that will be applied to all of my <javac> tags.

Comment: @szxnyc For which you can design a macro : refer to ant's `macrodef` task and make use of _default_ `attribute` & _implicit_ `element`

Comment: ah but it seems like I would have to change all the direct references to <javac> to a new <marcrodef>, is that correct? I'm just looking for the easiest/least impact change to our build file.